# How could I evaluate $\sum_{r=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{r\sqrt{r+1}}}\;?$

Tags: limits, summation

How could I evaluate $\displaystyle\,\sum_{r=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{r\sqrt{r+1}}}\;?$

I have tried the substitution $r=k^2-1$, but this yields a sum with a square root as the starting point ($\sqrt2$).

$$\int_1^\infty{\frac{1}{\lfloor x^2 \rfloor}}=\int_1^\sqrt{2}{1}dx+\int_\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{3}{\frac{1}{2}}dx+\int_\sqrt{3}^\sqrt{4}{\frac{1}{3}}dx\,+...$$ I think.

Comment: Why do you believe that this has a closed-form solution?

Comment: @MarkViola I don't know if it does.

Comment: Have you tried numerical computation to see if obvious  value comes out ?

Comment: @EDX I mean, yeah it seems to go to something like 2.04288.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+of+1%2F%28r*sqrt%28r%2B1%29%29+from+1+to+inf&dataset=) knows no closed form. Why do you want to evaluate the sum? If you just want to prove it converges, or bound or approximate it, those are all more tractable questions.

Comment: @J.G. It was just a question that arose from an integral I made up: $\int_1^\infty{\frac{1}{\lfloor x^2 \rfloor}}$. Well, guess no fun problem for my friends.

Comment: Your integral can be rewritten as $\sum_{r\ge1}\frac{\sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r}}{r}=\sum_{r\ge1}\frac{1}{r(\sqrt{r+1}+\sqrt{r})}$. How did you reduce that to the problem at hand?

Comment: @JakubGluszko How does the integral of the reciprocal of the floor of $x^2$ lead to the sum you wish to evaluate.  I believe that we have

$$\int_1^\infty \frac1{\lfloor x^2\rfloor}\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n+1}}\frac1{n}\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})} $$

Comment: @J.G. I believe the integral is $\sqrt{2}-1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{4}}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}+...=-1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6} +\frac{\sqrt{4}}{12}+...=-1+$ the sum in the question.

Comment: Could you edit the fuller details of that calculation into the question?

Comment: No closed from Exist however this coverges it is easy to see as , By p-test

Comment: Okay you can use Abel's technique somehow, I am guessing okay.

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas I don't know what that is, but I'm trying something different because apparently I don't need to evaluate this sum.

Comment: Okay that's nice keep going, Noone knows when the great league forward is going to come best of luck.

Comment: @MarkViola Hello I understand what you did here, but I'm not sure what I did wrong. Also, how would I evaluate the integral you wrote?

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas You meant "great leap," not "great league," right?

Comment: Forget it's in theory of everything movie dialogue

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{r\sqrt{r+1}}}$$ let us use
$$\frac{1}{r\sqrt{r+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{4^n} \binom{2 n}{n} r^{-n-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{r\sqrt{r+1}}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{4^n} \binom{2 n}{n}\, \zeta \left(\frac{2 n+3}{2} \right)$$ but this is rather slow even if alternetive.

If you use Euler-McLaurin summation formula (limited to $f^{(5)}(r)$), you have
$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{r\sqrt{r+1}}}\sim \frac{6174871}{10321920 \sqrt{2}}+2 \sinh ^{-1}(1)=2.1857\cdots$$  instead of $2.1840\cdots$